# How do I get my code to overlay all of my groups of images correctly without throwing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception

I am overlaying multiple images and giving them their own file names. I am overlaying each bottom image (in a folder named bottom with 12 images) with each top image (in a folder named top with 10 images). My naming procedure works, and my overlaying procedure works, but my code, for some reason, only goes through the first 3 images in the top folder and returns a NullPointerExeption, while going through all of the bottom images. How can I make it iterate through all of my images?

The code that I tried is:

```java
package images;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
public class overlay_images {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,NullPointerException {
        File bottom = new File("C:\\Users\\mymsa\\Documents\\Mathmatical Docs\\Java Math\\images\\all_img\\bottom");
        File top = new File("C:\\Users\\mymsa\\Documents\\Mathmatical Docs\\Java Math\\images\\all_img\\top_lantern_blocks");
        int x = bottom.listFiles().length;
        int y = top.listFiles().length;
        BufferedImage[][] imgs = new BufferedImage[x*y][2];
        BufferedImage[] newImgs = new BufferedImage[x*y];
        String newFileName = "";
        for(int n=0;n<x*y;n++) {
            imgs[n] = new BufferedImage[] {ImageIO.read(bottom.listFiles()[n%x]),
                ImageIO.read(top.listFiles()[n/x])};
            newImgs[n] = new BufferedImage(16,16,BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
            for(int i=0;i<16;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<16;j++) {
                    int ptop = ImageIO.read(top.listFiles()[n/x]).getRGB(i,j);
                    int pbttm = ImageIO.read(bottom.listFiles()[n%x]).getRGB(i,j);
                    if(ptop/(2^24)==0) {newImgs[n].setRGB(i,j,pbttm);} else {newImgs[n].setRGB(i,j,ptop);}
                }
            }
            newImgs[n].setRGB(8,15,imgs[n%x][0].getRGB(8,15));
            newFileName = "C:\\Users\\mymsa\\Documents\\Mathmatical Docs\\Java Math\\images\\all_img\\lantern_blocks\\";
            newFileName+= top.listFiles()[n/x].getName().replace(".png","") + "_";
            newFileName+= bottom.listFiles()[n%x].getName();
            newFileName = newFileName.replace("bulb", "lantern");
            newFileName = newFileName.replace("_off", "_block");
            ImageIO.write(newImgs[n],"png",new File(newFileName));
        }
    }
}
```

VSCode is showing that line 21 is causing the error: `int ptop = ImageIO.read(top.listFiles()[n/x]).getRGB(i,j);`
How can I fix this error?
I just redid the code to iterate directly through files instead of through numbers and I am getting the same error at line 17:

```java
package images;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
public class overlay_images {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,NullPointerException {
        File bottom = new File("C:\\Users\\mymsa\\Documents\\Mathmatical Docs\\Java Math\\images\\all_img\\bottom");
        File top = new File("C:\\Users\\mymsa\\Documents\\Mathmatical Docs\\Java Math\\images\\all_img\\top_lantern_blocks");
        BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(16,16,BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        String newFileName = "";
        for(File m:bottom.listFiles()) {
            for(File n:top.listFiles()) {
                newImg=new BufferedImage(16,16,BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
                for(int i=0;i<16;i++) {
                    for(int j=0;j<16;j++) {
                        int ptop = ImageIO.read(n).getRGB(i,j);
                        int pbttm = ImageIO.read(m).getRGB(i,j);
                        if(ptop/(2^24)==0) {newImg.setRGB(i,j,pbttm);} else {newImg.setRGB(i,j,ptop);}
                }
            }
            newImg.setRGB(8,15,ImageIO.read(m).getRGB(8,15));
            newFileName = "C:\\Users\\mymsa\\Documents\\Mathmatical Docs\\Java Math\\images\\all_img\\lantern_blocks\\";
            newFileName+= n.getName().replace(".png","") + "_";
            newFileName+= m.getName();
            newFileName = newFileName.replace("bulb", "lantern");
            newFileName = newFileName.replace("_off", "_block");
            ImageIO.write(newImg,"png",new File(newFileName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would do this differently.  Instead of trying to use `for(int n=0;n<x*y;n++) {` and then some fancy pancy maths, I'd simply loop over the `bottom` files and the loop over the `top` files independently

Comment: I am way too math oriented! I'll try that!

Comment: I just tried that and I am getting the same error at line 17 now!

Comment: So, two things.  1) Make sure that the image you're trying to load is actually a supported image (and isn't corrupted in some way); 2) it has enough pixels (`i`/`j`) for `getRGB` to work.

Comment: @MadProgrammer both of those conditions are true. All of my images are exactly the same size (16 by 16 px). It says that the return value of "javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(java.io.File)" is null, which must mean it thinks there are only 3 images in my top folder, while I have 10 total .png photos.

Comment: Again, I would, print out the image names as you try and load, identify the image which is causing your problems, either remove it or check that it's not corrupted

Comment: I just checked again, none of the images are corrupted? Maybe it has to do with the names of the images? The code is only doing the first 3 images... I'm just trying to find patterns here.

Comment: Try a different test - try just loading the images - it's possible that one of the image is in an unsupported format (but named `.png`) - *"ImageIO.read(file); will return null if no registered ImageReader is found."*.  I would, personally, pre-load all the images, so that you're not having to read the bottom images n number of times

Comment: I just did that. They all open fine and all are .png files

Comment: Well, I'm at the end of my list - the only reason to return `null` from `ImageIO.read` is the supplied image is unsupported